Errors while building from source RQt for Arch Linux
I'm trying to install RQt for ROS2 Iron something from the official guide https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/How-To-Guides/RQt-Source-Install.html
I get this error
ros_ws rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro bouncy -y --skip-keys "console_bridge fastcdr fastrtps libopensplice67 rti-connext-dds-5.3.1 urdfdom_headers"
>>>
WARNING: given --rosdistro bouncy but ROS_DISTRO is "iron". Ignoring environment.
WARNING: ROS_PYTHON_VERSION is unset. Defaulting to 3
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
qt_dotgraph: No definition of [python3-pygraphviz] for OS [arch]
cv_bridge: No definition of [python3-opencv] for OS [arch]

Yes, the packages python-opencv and python-pygraphviz are installed in my machine. But they were installed from the AUR, not from the official repository (they're not present!), and I'm sure that's the problem: in a previous post I found out rosdep wasn't any accepting any python dependency that wasn't strictly from the official repository.
Has anyone an idea on how I could move? Thanks in advance

I improved the situation but didn't fully solve the issue. Long story short: there was no definition for the Arch package in the python.yaml. I created a pull request containing the patch.
sudo nano /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d/
then replace
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml
with my patch
yaml https://raw.githubusercontent.com/enfff/rosdistro/patch-1/rosdep/python.yaml
The new error is
cv_bridge: No definition of [libboost-python-dev] for OS [arch]
and I can't find a single package in the official repo that provides it! I thought it was either boost or boost-libs, but it's neither apparently.
